# Android device shows up in DDMS but does not run my app

Tags: android, android-emulator, device, galaxy, ddms

As the title says, my Android phone is plugged into my computer and showing up in the DDMS, but when I click run to run my app, it just uses the emulator. I have checked the phone name and serial number, it is correct. I have checked the box on the phone "allow USB debugging". It's a Samsung Galaxy phone. It did run another app I made but I'm new to Android so this is the second app I have tested. No one seems to have asked this question so it sounds uncommon. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the top two answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178851/install-and-run-an-app-on-multiple-devices-with-a-single-click-under-eclipse

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly Thanks! That worked. I selected launch on all compatible devices from the run configurations options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your app in the Package explorer (usually on the left side in Eclipse) now select Run>Run Configurations in the Menu.

A Window will pop up, search for "Android Application">YOUR APP NAME and select the "target tab". Make sure "Always prompt to pick device" is checked.

Comment: Thanks. Just before you replied I clicked the option just below that one "launch on all compatible devices" and it worked, so i'm guessing your way works too.